# How can I use where in select with group by

Tags: c#, .net, linq, select, devexpress

```
var packs = from r in new XPQuery<Roll>(session)
            join p in new XPQuery<Pack>(session) on r.Pack equals p
            group new { r, p } by new { r.Pack } into gb
            select new
            {
                Length = gb.Sum(x => x.r.Length),
                ALength = gb.Where(a => a.r.Grade == "A").Sum(x => x.r.Length),
            };

gcPack.DataSource = packs;
```

I know `ALenght = gb.Where(a => a.r.Grade == "A").Sum(x => x.r.Lenght)` causes runtime error and without it the code is ok. Is it possible to use where in select statement like this.

Error:

> Additional information: Property path 'r' is incorrect for type 'DataRepository.Roll' because member 'DataRepository.Roll.r' does not exist.

Comment: try `gb.Where(a => a.Grade == "A")`

Comment: it doesn't work @Habib